# Reading and writing data into sql server simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a service which continuously writes data in a separate thread into SQL database.Now from the same service if i am trying to read from the same table, since i already am writing into it,I get this exception : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
So can anyone help me how to do this simultaneously?

Here s my code  for reading data:

public Collection ReadData(string query)
        {

```
        {

            _result = new Collection<string[]>();
            string[] tempResult;
            SqlDataReader _readerRead;
            using (_command = new SqlCommand(query, _readConnection))
            {
                _readerRead = _command.ExecuteReader();
                while (_readerRead.Read())
                {
                    tempResult = new string[4];
                    tempResult[0] = _reader[0].ToString();
                    tempResult[1] = _reader[1].ToString();
                    tempResult[2] = _reader[2].ToString();
                    tempResult[3] = _reader[3].ToString();
                    _result.Add(tempResult);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Name : {0} Type : {1} Value : {2} timestamp : {3}", _reader[0], _reader[1], _reader[2], _reader[3]);

                }
                if (_readerRead != null)
                {
                    _readerRead.Close();
                }
                _readConnection.Close();
                return _result;

            }
        }
    }
```

and here it is for writing to it :

```
public void WriteData(Collection<TagInfo> tagInfoList)
    {

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < tagInfoList.Count; i++)
        {
           using( _command = new SqlCommand(insert statement here)
            {
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", tagInfoList[i].Name);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", tagInfoList[i].TagType);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", tagInfoList[i].Value);
                _reader = _command.ExecuteReader();
                if (_reader != null)
                {
                    _reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using 1 connection for both reading and writing?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @WouterdeKort ya i am using the same connection for both.Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its possible to do, using a separate connection I would question why you need to do this.

If you are reading and writing data to one table in the same service you will be placing unnecessary load on one SQL table, and depending on the number of queries you intend to make this could cause you problems.  If you already have this data (in a different thread) why not Marshall the data from the background thread to where you need it as you write it into the database, and you don't need to read the data anymore.

However.... it is difficult to give an fair answer without seeing the code/what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: I want to read previously written data from the table, and into the same table I keep writing the present data.What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could use a ReaderWriterLockSlim and Add a row to your collection after you have written the row to the database.  Or if you are using the backgroundworkerthread you could use progresschanged to update the collection.  How many rows of data do you need to 'read', and what do you need to do with this data?  I assume this is a windows service and you are spawning separate threads for writing data and reading data?

Comment: ya windows service.I generate report based on the time stamp of the row.User enters the time range and then I query for that table for the time range entered by the user.And ya I am reading and writing in separate threads.So how do I do it? can you please help me out?

Comment: Is the string query passed into ReadData always the same, or are you passing a parameter/different where clause through in that query?

Comment: No,its like each time user may enter different time stamp ranges.So the query depends on the time range entered by the user. its something like this :select * from Table where(day(timestamp)between day1  and  day2 and MONTH(timestamp)between  month1 and month2

Comment: In that case it would be quite refactor and extra data storage to hold data you need in state.  Now I understand what you are trying to achieve it would be easiest to use a different SQL Connection, although this will add some extra load on the db.  When you instantiate the SQLCommands Create New Connections for each one separately as Simon has suggested in his post, do this for Read and Write:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx  _command = new SqlCommand(query, New SQLConnection("ConnectionString"))  Storing changes in memory would be more efficient but too much to explain

Answer (score 5):

You need a different SQLConnection to the database for your writer. You cannot use the same db connection for both.

Comment: Also you should finally close datareader after process the data it common mistake ppl forget to close the datareader